# I want to animate this motion - Hula hoop

Tags: animation

I want to make a character move their hips but keep the feet "locked" in place.

I asked this question on Blender Artists but didn't get very many
replies... (.blend file included).

https://blenderartists.org/t/posing-example-hula-hoop/1371842/

Comment: it just looks like the hip goes from left to right and also gradually down?

Comment: if you use IK for the legs then the feet will stay locked in place